# Best practices for building a form wizard with multiple steps in plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, submit, wizard

I want to make a question-answer web application. This will consist of multiple forms.
When the user clicks next button the next question should be loaded (like step 1, 2,etc). So what is the best practise to create multiple forms?

Should i create different page for each form?

Should i validate them with **javascript** or **php**?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
          <form id="form1" class="w3-container" method="post" action="#">
 
  <p>      
  <label>Answer 1</label>
  <input name="in1" class="w3-input w3-border" type="text"></p>
  <p>      
  <label>Answer 2</label>
  <input id="in2"  class="w3-input w3-border" type="text"></p>
  <p>      
  <label>Answer 3</label>
  <input id="in3" class="w3-input w3-border" type="text"></p>
  <p>      
  <label>Answer 4</label>
  <input id="in4"   class="w3-input w3-border" type="text"></p>
 <p><button class="w3-btn w3-block w3-indigo">next</button></p>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

- The validation should always be validated on **server-side**, because client-side could be manipulated and changed by the client. You also could validate some states on client-side, just to be more "friendly usable".
- You could create a form on each page or load the next using AJAX by example, while the server validate the integrity of questions/anwsers at the submission.

Comment: i found something on w3-schools but it has too much javascript: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_form_steps

Comment: @csandreas1 In this example, there is only one form, but all elements are hidden and displayed for each step. It could be a solution, while all is validated on server side.

Comment: How could i make a form on each page and take their values when submit in the final stage?

Comment: @csandreas1 You could store anwsers in session, by example. And remove when the final stage is validated.